# HTML Button to run a PHP script following a second click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, raspberry-pi

I am using HTML on a Raspberry Pi to control relays, currently I have a button for the On and another for the Off of the GPIO, I was wondering if there was a way I could press a single button once to call the On.php and press the same button a second time to call the Off.php without leaving the page.

Right now one button moves to the PHP script page which turns the GPIO On and then returns to the home page, the Off button does the same. This is a bad method but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Seting a global variable to calculate the times of your clicking (flag==0). Then writing something to define which functions you want to use.

Comment: This is all held on a webpage, if I reload the website wouldn't the variable reset and turn off what I had turned on?

Comment: Google the jquery framework. There is a toggle function, which can allow you to use different based on the times of your click.

Answer (score 0):

I used a checkbox for the input, a function is called when the box is clicked which then checks if it is ticked or not, the code then uses a variable to decide what state the GPIO Pin should be in.